# How can I access text inside an input within a template?

Tags: vue.js

My objective is to get text from an input that's in a template. Not sure how to go about retrieving this. I'm using Vue; Note must be available in Vue.js, no external sources

The Template:

```
<template id="addmodal">
        <div class="modal-mask">
            <div class="modal-wrapper">
                <div class="modal-container">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <slot name="header">
                            Enter Course Information: 
                        </slot>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <slot name="body">
                            Course Name
                            <input type="text" ref="coursename" placeholder="Numbers Don't Lie 101">
                            Course Grade
                            <input type="text" ref ="coursemark" placeholder="100">
                        </slot>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <slot name="footer">
                            <button class="modal-default-button" @click="confirmCourse">
                                Submit New Course
                            </button>
                            <button class="modal-cancel-button" @click="cancelCourse">
                                Cancel
                            </button>
                        </slot>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

I need to access coursename and coursemark. This can be done fairly easily when not inside a template. As it is right now the code executes stating .value is undefined.

```
var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                courses: [],
                confirmModal: false,
                confirmAdd: false,
                selectedCourse: null
            },

            methods: {
                  addCourse2: function addCourse2() {
                        this.confirmAdd = false;
                        var course = this.$refs.coursename.value;
                        var mark = this.$refs.coursemark.value;
                        if (course) {
                            this.courses.push(new Course(course, mark));
                            this.$refs.newcourse.value = "";
                            this.$refs.newmark.value = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

EDIT:
Forgot to add the component section

```
Vue.component("add-modal", {
            template: "#addmodal",
            props: ["open", "course", "mark"],
            methods: {
                confirmCourse: function confirmCourse() {
                    alert(this.$refs.coursename.value);
                    this.$emit("confirm");// GET 
                },
                cancelCourse: function cancelCourse() {
                    this.$emit("cancel");
                }
            }
        });
```

Forgive me in advance, I feel this is something rather easy I'm missing as a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use v-model. or if it is in other component. you can use $emit

Comment: There is an emit event that displays the template. How would I use emit to send 3 pieces of data?

Comment: What do you mean by 3 pieces of data ?

Comment: The template uses an emit event to be displayed;
<transition name="appear">
            <add-modal @course="coursename" @mark="coursemark" v-if='confirmAdd' @confirm='addCourse2' @cancel="cancelCourse"></add-modal>
        </transition>

I would either need to have 3 emit events or have a way to send the data of coursename, coursemark, and the bool value that shows the template

Comment: for multiple emit in a single component. much better to use emit and sync. just like this


`<input type="text" @input="test">
<input type="text" @input="test2">`


`data() {
  return {
    test: ""
    test2: ""
  }
}`



`watch: {
  test(value) {
    this.$emit("update:test", value)
  },
  test2(value) {
    this.$emit("update:test2", value)
  }
}`


-------------------------
`<your-component :test.sync="testValue" :test2.sync="testValue2">`